# is it good to attach an extra battery parallel to a small-inverter system

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, ups

I have a small inverter system.

### Desire:

increasing Power-Bank's battery backup

### Possible Solution:

Want to connect another similar battery in parallel to the older battery. Or probably two new batteries discarding older one.

### Request:

I have no idea if this is feasible. Is this a good idea?

If not , could you please suggest me some better idea?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: You want to ensure they're not accidentally recharging each other.

Comment: Would there be any problem if they are recharging each other?? any ways to stop that?

Comment: If they are recharging each other, and especially if they're not rechargeable batteries (this doesn't necessarily mean you can do it with rechargeable ones), they will leak and corrode your contacts and anything near it. And it gets messy.

Comment: It's unlikely that the charge, discharge, and test functions of a UPS will all operate normally with a significantly different battery.  Is a bigger box, with a bigger battery, not available?

Comment: I was curious to expand its capacity by scaling the battery up. Is it possible to connect a single battery with bigger capacity?

Comment: There are two problems, 1) you shouldn't have asked this question here. Read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic 2) The batteries should be matched closely and the charge discharge circuit might not be rated for double the input load of two batteries

Comment: I'd say go ahead, it will probably work just fine. Just be careful when initially connecting the batteries to each other because heavy current will flow if they're not (held) at exactly the same voltage.

Comment: A single battery with a bigger capacity is most likely to increase performance in the sense of how long the inverter supplies power, but not in the sense of how much current it can supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have a 12V battery with a 8 Ah capacity.  The simplest way to increase its capacity is to replace it with a higher capacity battery. Kinetik Audio (at www.Kinetikaudio.com) makes several types with different capacities.
If you want to use several batteries, then you need to "protect" them by using one diode per battery (to the common rail) to prevent the batteries from recharging each other.  The drawback is that the load current is limited to the current capacity of the diodes.  Also, the charging capacity of the charger may not be sufficient to recharge the batteries in a "reasonable" time.

Comment: Also the diodes will prevent them recharging at all, will they not?

Comment: okay then I am considering my idea to be invalid

Comment: Transistor, a second set of diodes between the batteries and the charger should allow charging.  However, this means that the output voltage will be two diode drops below the charger voltage, rather than only one diode drop.